# Webview showing issue Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, webview

So I have a Webview in my activity and it runs fine on one tablet but when I install the app on another tablet it just show a blank screen.

One possible problem that I could think of is the differences in android version.. the one that works the version is 5.0.2 and the one that doesn't work version is 6.0.1.. But there could be other problems too, I don't have any clues.

Does anybody know of this problem? Please help!!

[Picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lk7wL.jpg)

Comment: Are you correctly requested necessary permissions for Android 6? Check this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#permissions)

Comment: Found out the problem... It's because I didn't have Android System Webview installed on the tablet..